# Can I use source test1.sh with gnome-terminal -x?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, scripts

I am executing 2 shell scripts from the main using source.

main.sh:

```
#/bin/sh

a=1
b=2
c=3

gnome-terminal -x sh -c ". ./test1.sh|less" (note the source ".")

gnome-terminal -x sh -c ". ./test2.sh|less"
...
...
```

test1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "a="$a #doesn't print anything
```

I was able to do following 2 separately but when I combine, I am not able to access variables of main into other files

1. `gnome-terminal -x sh -c "test1.sh|less"` #able to execute in separate terminal
2. `. ./test1.sh` #able to access variables from main.sh in test1.sh

Answer (score 0):

You must `export` any variables that need to be referenced in a subshell.

In your example put the statement:

```
export a b c
```

somewhere before you invoke `gnome-terminal`. Alternatively, define the variables with the export statement:

```
export a=1 b=2 c=3
```

I presume you source `test1.sh` in an attempt to work around the `export` requirement (since a sourced file is interpreted by the sourcing shell, not executed in a subshell). What you are overlooking is that opening a `gnome-terminal` will start a *new* shell.

Answer (score 0):

**Variables are not shared between separate shell instances.** The only way I know of to access a variable from a script started in a different shell is to have the script write the variable to a file and then access that file.

Now, in your special case, you can send the value of `$a` variable from main script to test script as follow:

**main.sh:**

```
#/bin/sh

a=1
b=2
c=3

gnome-terminal -x sh -c "test1.sh '$a' | less" # without source "."

# ... some other code
```

**test1.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

a=$1

echo "a=$a"
```

or, use `export` as [awets](https://askubuntu.com/users/134479/zwets) said in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/352569/147044).